# php what information is by default sent when requesting ip?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know what information that my website receives beside

`$_SERVER['value']?`

is there other fields can be obtained ?

Thank you

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)` and [here's the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). If you're looking for other superglobal variables other than `$_SERVER`, you can [check out the comprehensive list of predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivially answered in the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($_SERVER)` or `print_r($_SERVER)` show you all output of `$_SERVER` global's

Comment: you're welcome friend